# Excel 2010 F2-Enter Macro Button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a chart with two columns that count horizontally across the grid cells with a specific color fill. (=CountCellsByColor(##:##,#) There are 24 Rows in each column.

I now want to create a macro button in a particular cell so the user can click the button and the columns will auto update.  Currently this is accomplished by clicking into a cell, pressing F2 then Enter, which is fine but if I can make it simpler all the better.

This is what I have, I created a commandButton from the Developer tab (Insert, Button); Then in the VBA screen the following code;

```
Sub RefreshCells()
 Dim r As Range, rr As Range
 Set rr = Selection
 For Each r In rr
     r.Select
     Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
     Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
     DoEvents
 Next
 End Sub
```

I get a restricted use error that pops up after I click the button, it works once but that's it then locks the rest of the cells from editing.  I have a number of VBA codes running on the sheet that allow users of the sheet to simply click certain cells to turn them different colors.

Comment: Have you tried a search? This site expects some effort shown by the user asking a question. Show what you've found and tried and what doesn't work the way you expect

Comment: Sorry, This is what I have, I created a commandButton from the Developer tab (Insert, Button); Then in the VBA screen the following code; Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sub RefreshCells()
 Dim r As Range, rr As Range
 Set rr = Selection
 For Each r In rr
     r.Select
     Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
     Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
     DoEvents
 Next
 End Sub     Then I get a value entered not valid code error message when I try to work in the cells after clicking the button

Comment: That sounds promising. But what is F2 for? Is that the special key that initiates the macro? Where is the macro function code?

Comment: I use the F2-Enter function to goggle between Edit/Enter Mode which then allows the two columns that are running the CountCellsByColor formula update. (Just like refreshing the page which runs the colorcount code)  Because these columns are counting cells based on their colors they don't auto update like they would if they were counting data numbers

Answer (score 0):

I was making this far too complicated!  If I may attempt to answer my own question, here is what I did to solve this,

Under Developer Tab, I hit Record Macro Then F2 Enter followed by Stop Record and saved that function. Then I created a Button under the developer tab and assigned it that macro.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
    Range("D33:D34").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("D35").Select
End Sub
```

It's probably not right but it seems to have the same effect of clicking into a cell, hitting F2 + Enter .  The columns that don't have an automatic count update perfect, no errors, no bugs!